# SwiftUI NavigationBarItem Hover Effect on iPadOS

Tags: swiftui, ipados

When using UIKit, the UIBarButtonItems automatically get support for the highlight hover effect when using a pointer in iOS 13.4+.

After updating some views to use SwiftUI, the equivalent NavigationBarItem modifiers do not have a highlight hover effect. Is this a bug, not supported, or implemented in a different way?